# how to apply animateContentSize from center?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

Actually the compose is animating from the center, but its content, which is a button, is moving from top left to center while animating the compose.

I want the button to animate from the center. I tried adding .animateContentSize to button, and the box as well, but still the button animates from top left to center.

Here's the code:

```
@Composable
fun TopScreen(
    isScaffold: MutableState<Boolean>,
){
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = !isScaffold.value,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .animateContentSize(
                animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 500, easing = LinearEasing)
            )
    ){
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.LightGray),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ){
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    isScaffold.value = true
                },
                modifier = Modifier

            ) {
                Text(text = "GO TO BOTTOM SCREEN")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `Modiifer.animateContentSize()` with `AnimatedVisibility` composable it has `scaleIn` and `scaleOut` transitions. All of the transitions you can use are available in official document.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/composables-modifiers#enter-exit-transition

Also you can use state-hoisting instead of passing and modifying `State`.

```
@Composable
fun TopScreen(
    isScaffold: Boolean,
    onChange: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = !isScaffold,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        enter = scaleIn(tween(durationMillis = 500, easing = LinearEasing)),
        exit = scaleOut(tween(durationMillis = 500, easing = LinearEasing))

    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.LightGray),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    onChange(isScaffold.not())
                },
                modifier = Modifier

            ) {
                Text(text = "GO TO BOTTOM SCREEN")
            }
        }
    }
}
```